# s3hook download_fileobj to temp file empty. what tests can be performed?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, airflow, boto3, airflow-2.x

I'm using the s3hook download_fileobj, that is saved to a temp file. When I try to read the contents of the temp file to make sure the s3 file was saved to the temp file its empty, and it wasn't saved! (see the last line where I print the lines) I also listed the keys to make sure the s file is there and I have the correct bucket info and I do see the key there. Are there any other tests I can do to see why this isn't working?

This is my code:

```
    s3hook = S3Hook("my conn")

    s3_key = f'moft/2023-05.txt'
    logging.info(f'Downloading s3 file {s3_key} to be encrypted')

    keys = s3hook.list_keys(bucket_name="my bucket", prefix='moft/', delimiter="/")
    logging.info(f'keys: {keys}')

    s3_obj = s3hook.get_key(key=s3_key, bucket_name="my bucket")
    logging.info(f's3_obj {s3_obj}')
    logging.info(f'self.s3_bucket {"my bucket"}')

    # dl file from s3, to encrypt
    temp_file = f'/tmp/airflow1/file_to_encrypt_2023-05.txt'

    # Writing downloaded to /tmp/
    data = open(temp_file, 'wb')
    s3_obj.download_fileobj(data)
    logging.info(f'data_name {data.name}')

    with open(temp_file, 'r') as f:
        logging.info(f.read())
```

Comment: You're not closing the file you open for writing, meaning data might still be in flight not yet flushed to disk.  Either call `data.close()`, or better, use `with open(temp_file, 'wb') as data:` to open it and auto-close it when you exit the block of code.

Comment: @AnonCoward - when would i do data.close() after the download_fileobj? and if i used your second answer, would I just indent those 2 lines under that 'with' statement, meaning the "download_fileobj" and the "logging"?
Also, do you think i shoudl add data.seek(0) after the "downlaod_fileobj"?

Comment: You should do it because you're done with the data object at that point, and to instruct the underlying library that you expect the file to be complete, so it should flush to disk now.

Comment: @AnonCoward - this worked for me, I did both the `seek` and the `with open(temp_file, 'wb') as data:`